# Where is mongo shell installed on Amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I successfully installed MongoDB on an Amazon Linux AMI by following this tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/

The log (`/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`) shows that mongo is up-and-running, so I know it was correctly installed.

However, I can't figure out how to access the mongo shell. I know the shell package was installed because:

```
$ sudo yum install mongodb-org-shell
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
Package mongodb-org-shell-3.0.12-1.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Where can I find/how do I run the Mongo shell on my EC2 instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your "mongodb installation dir" (Common Path is /etc/mongo):

```
cd <mongodb installation dir>
```

Type ./bin/mongo to start mongo:

```
./bin/mongo
```

If you have added the /bin to the PATH environment variable, you can just type mongo instead of ./bin/mongo.

To display the database you are using, type db:

```
db
```

The operation should return test, which is the default database. To switch databases, issue the use  helper, as in the following example:

```
use <database>
```

Comment: My FTP client was caching the entire filesystem. The mongo install directory appeared after refresh...